# Handeling XML Soap Response With zapier NodeJS

Tags: node.js, xml, soap, zapier

I have a XML Soap Response in this format , Which Has following info
Username: 
Fulname: 
State: 
State Duration:

```
        <return>
            <columns>
                <values>
                    <data>Username</data>
                    <data>Full Name</data>
                    <data>State</data>
                    <data>State Duration</data>
                </values>
            </columns>
            <rows>
                <values>
                    <data>user1@test.com</data>
                    <data>User1</data>
                    <data>Logged Out</data>
                    <data>309</data>
                </values>
            </rows>
            <rows>
                <values>
                    <data>user2@test.com</data>
                    <data>User2</data>
                    <data>Logged In</data>
                    <data>165</data>
                </values>
            </rows>
            <rows>
                <values>
                    <data>user3@test.com</data>
                    <data>User3</data>
                    <data>Logged Out</data>
                    <data>109</data>
                </values>
            </rows>
       </return>
```

If I want to get total number of Logged Out users, I use my code

```
var LoggedOutCt = inputData.tempInput.split("Logged Out").length;
output = [{LoggedOutCt: LoggedOutCt}]
```

This gives me output as
LoggedOutCt: 2

How can I also get the name of users who are logged out 
Like 
LoggedOutCt : 2
Names: User1, User 3

And the Sum of "State Duration" of all users 
that is sum of : 309 + 165 + 109

Answer (score 0):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team.

If you're working with XML as if it is plain text, you're gonna have a bad time. My I would look for a way to parse XML into a more friendly format and work on it like a regular data structure. Unfortunately, node.js doesn't have a native xml parser, so you've got two options:

1. Make a little CLI app ([docs](https://github.com/zapier/zapier-platform-cli#does-zapier-support-xml-soap-apis)) that will parse your XML and you can work with it like json
2. Use a python code step, which *does* have native XML parsing. You can follow the instructions [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/xml-parsing-python/) to iterate over your `./rows/values` and check if the user is logged out.

Hopefully that gets you rolling the right direction!

Comment: Hey David, 
Thanks a lot for the reply 
Just a quick question as I am a bit new in programming
Starting with Python in Zapier 
I am using
from xml.etree import ElementTree
`code`
root = ElementTree.fromstring(input_data)
is this correct?
`code` I mean zapier accepts input_data or something else

Comment: not quite - `input_data` is a dict (equivalent to javascript's object) so you'll want to use `input_data['my_string']`, where 'my_string' is whatever the name of the key you're setting in the UI is. Also, it'll be easier to write/debug you're not code not on Zapier and then paste it in when it's ready and working